# Is .NET Protected Configuration Current?

Tags: .net, configuration-files

One of our .NET applications must call an external web service and I am looking for a way to securely store the credentials in the app.config. From reading a bunch of forums, the best(?) way to do this would be to use ASP.NET protected configuration. In our case, the application is deployed on multiple machines, so RSA would be more appropriate than DPAPI.

I have written a quick proof-of-concept 'Config File Encrypter' console application and this appears to work on my local machine at least. My concern is that this technique was introduced ~10 years ago, and most forum post are from this era. The MSDN page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx) states that this is 'retired content' but I haven't been able to find a more contemporary alternative.

Should I be looking elsewhere? This is an enterprise production system, so securing the credentials correctly is critical.

Comment: Talk more about ''the credentials". Do you want to protect it against anyone (including the user of your apps), or just anyone except that user? That makes the answers completely different.

Comment: The 'credentials' are a username/pwd provisioned for the .NET application to be able to call a web service (i.e. basic authentication). I want the application to be able to decrypt the username/pwd to call the service, but I don't want clear-text username/pwd to be visible if someone opens the app.config file.There is no requirement for specific users - if they can access the application, then the application must be able to decrypt the credentials.

Comment: You might learn from Windows activation or any other production protection mechanism, https://www.howtogeek.com/182847/htg-explains-how-does-windows-activation-work/ or to use an existing software licensing product. Then the end users with the activated software can use the activation key to access your back end service, as authentication token. Unfortunately .NET's protected configuration is not what you should waste time on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't see how this would solve this particular issue. The web service being called requires a username/pwd so these value must be stored locally.